# Usar CDN como paquete NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuex, vuetify

Estoy iniciando en NuxtJS. Estoy intentando usar tecnologías recientes a un proyecto.

Por ahora no quiero tener paquetes como Vue, Vuetify entre otros en el servidor, ya que me seria carga adicional en la transferencia de datos del servidor.

He decidido usar el cdn de Vue, VueRouter, Vuetify y otros pero no logro incluirlos como paquetes externos desde un cdn en NuxtJS y usarlos como por ejemplo ‘**import Vue from Vue**’.

Ya he intentado colocar en 'modules' un "publicPath" y en 'plugins: ‘src’' pero me genera error ya que no es enlace.

Por ejemplo esta es la forma para paquetes externos pero en el mismo servidor https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#external-packages.

Alguien me podría guiar como lograr realizar ya que deseo usar en lo mínimo el ancho de banda del servidor.

Actualizacion:

Por ejemplo en la documentación permite usar paquetes externos pero cuando pongo un enlace genera un error

```
export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js
' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: El motor de NuxtJS es Vue, por defecto incluye vue-router [Routing](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/)

Answer (score 0):

Quizás lo que buscas es inyectar etiquetas `<script>` en el documento.

Lo que puedes hacer es, añadir esta configuración a tu archivo **nuxt.config.js**:

```
export default {
  head: {
    // ...
    script: [{
      src: 'https://example.com/etc.js'
    }, {
      innerHTML: `alert("Hola mundo")`
    }],
    __dangerouslyDisableSanitizers: ['script']
  }
}
```